# Definition of image of an element; what does it mean to say that a function takes all values of subset?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

Wikipedia Article on topic of [images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_an_element) that

> " Given $y$, the function $f$ is said to "take the value $y$ " or "take $y$ as a value" if there exists some $x$ in the function's domain such that $f(x)=y$. Similarly, given a set $S, f$ is said to "take a value in $S^{\text {" }}$ if there exists some $x$ in the function's domain such that $f(x) \in S$. However, " $f$ takes [all] values in $S^{\text {" }}$ and " $f$ is valued in $S^{\prime \prime}$ means that $f(x) \in S$ for every point $x$ in  $f^{\prime}$ s domain."

My Query
It is related to the the meaning of $"f$ take all values in $S"$. Does this means $S$ is the range? Or $S$ is a subset of actual range of $f?$ In my opinion, former one is correct because it is being said that for all $x$ belongs to $f$, domain $f(x)$ is belonging to $S$  or is it that $S\subseteq f(x)$ range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the range of $f(x)$. For example, for $sin(\theta$) , $S=\mathbb C$ (yes, you can define $sin(\theta)$ for the complex numbers).

Comment: Thanks thats what i was also thinking

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer No problem.